# Nidec gamma32 4pin pinout

Tags: fan, pinout, cooling

I have `Nidec Gamma32 D12F-24BS4 15BH2` blowing fan cooler. It has very strange coloring for wires: red-white-black-yellow.

Probably two of wires are GND and +24v and other two are signal and PWM. What is the correct pinout for this connector type?

Below I attach photo of this connector and photo with comparison to standard 3-pin molex connector.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the fan. It's always possible that this fan has a non-standard, proprietary connection.

Comment: I tried to find, but could not.

Answer (score 1):

It is partly answer to my question: black wire is GND and red wire is +24v.

It became clear after I saw the layout on the board:

[image]

The tracks on the board for the yellow and white wires are very thin, on the other hand the tracks for the red and black wires are thick.